# Remote login into Rails 2 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication, remote-forms

I am working on signing in a [Rails 2 app](http://www.zouz.com/) remotely. Given that Rails methods are RESTful by default, I am assuming all I have to do would be POSTing form data from the remote application (a Facebook App actually). For some reason, this doesn't seem to work, I've tried:

```
curl http://www.zouz.com/session -d user[email]=testing@blabla.com -d user[password]=whocares
```

which returns and empty result. I suspected Rails' built in forgery protection might be the cause, deactivating it won't make it work.

Is there something wrong with my method ?

EDIT : If it's any help, processing the same POST query with [HTTPRequester](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/httprequester/) does [work](http://pastebin.com/x4CFXcqE), although I provided the same input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working, thanks to the -u flag.

```
 curl --user testing@blabla.com:whocares http://192.168.1.19:3000
```

This is still cryptic to me, as I still don't know how it operates under the hood. Explanations are still welcome.

Comment: It sends the `Authorization` HTTP header to the server where the value is the Base64 encoded version of your authorization data (`testing@blabla.com:whocares`). You can see it working when you pass the `-v` option to curl.